# How can I complete a transaction without unlocking my account first?

Tags: web3js, transactions, parity

I need to call a (state-changing) function on my contract.

Here is how I am currently executing this transaction:

```
let transaction = contract.methods.myFunc();
await web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(ACCOUNT_ADDRESS, ACCOUNT_PASSWORD);
let gas = await transaction.estimateGas({from: ACCOUNT_ADDRESS, gasPrice: GAS_PRICE});
await transaction.send({from: ACCOUNT_ADDRESS, gasPrice: GAS_PRICE, gas: gas});
```

However, to my understanding, unlocking the account on my Ethereum client leaves a lot of security holes to deal with.

Is there any way for me to pass my credentials (account address and password) when I execute the transaction, instead of unlocking the account beforehand?

Documentation for `unlockAccount` is [here](https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-personal-module.html#personal_unlockaccount).

Documentation for `send` is [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html?highlight=deploy#methods-mymethod-send).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can just sign the transaction on your side and send a raw transaction, you will be doing this on python or java or another environment but not on your Ethereum client directly. So the risk is minimized.

Example:

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
dataTx = myContract.methods.myFunc(params).encodeABI(); //The encoded ABI of the method

var rawTx = {
  to: 'yourcantract address', 
  data:dataTx 
}

var tx = new Tx(rawTx);
tx.sign('yourprivateKey');

var serializedTx = tx.serialize();
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
.on('receipt', console.log);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. So I'm looking at functions `sign` and `signTransaction` [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sign). But neither one of them takes the private key / passphrase / password as input. So how exactly can it possibly replace `unlockAccount`?

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. I need to use function [`web3.eth.personal.signTransaction`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-personal.html#signTransaction) (not function `web3.eth.signTransaction`).

Comment: yes! [see here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html?highlight=rawtransaction#signtransaction)

Comment: For example, the function you suggested takes a transaction object as input. But the transaction object in my code - `contract.methods.myFunc()` - is completely different (and yes, both are referred to as *transaction object* in the docs).

Comment: Yes, you are right, take a look at my update. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I get `Returned error: Insufficient funds. The account you tried to send transaction from does not have enough funds` (an error which I didn't get when I used `unlockAccount`).

Comment: is as the error says, your account doesn't have enough funds.

Comment: As I said in my comment, this error does not occur when I unlock the account, hence the reason cannot possibly be that it "doesn't have enough funds".

Comment: Did you solve this?, let me know

Comment: I have used a slightly different code (purely `web3`, without `ethereumjs-tx`). Couldn't get it to work so posted a more detailed question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/51417/16043).