# Insufficient funds when using 'signTransaction' but not when using 'unlockAccount'

Tags: web3js, transactions, parity

I am trying to execute a transaction on a private network, using my account.

**The general flow:**

> Web3.js --> Parity node --> Private network

**The transaction:**

> Invoke a method in a contract deployed beforehand

---

My first approach was to unlock the account, and then send the transaction.

**The procedure:**

1. Create a transaction object for the method (see [Web3 docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id12)).
2. Unlock the account using my **password** (see [Parity docs](https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-personal-module.html#personal_unlockaccount)).
3. Send the transaction object (see [Web3 docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-send)).

**My code:**

```
let transaction = contract.methods.myFunc();
let options = {
    from: ACCOUNT_ADDRESS,
    gasPrice: GAS_PRICE,
    gas: await transaction.estimateGas()
};
await web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(ACCOUNT_ADDRESS, ACCOUNT_PASSWORD);
await transaction.send(options);
```

This seems to work just fine.

However, I have later realized that unlocking my account leaves a serious security breach, as others might be able to submit requests during the time the account is unlocked. Of course, this may be prevented in several different ways I suppose (for example, by checking the sender's IP). But I believe that I would be better off executing it without unlocking the account (i.e., instead of creating a problem and then trying to solve it, avoid the problem to begin with).

---

So my second approach is to sign the transaction, and only then send it.

**The procedure:**

1. Create a transaction object for the method (see [Web3 docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id12)).
2. Sign the transaction with my account's **private key** (see [Web3 docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html?highlight=rawtransaction#signtransaction)).
3. Send the signed transaction string to the Parity node (see [Web3 docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#eth-sendsignedtransaction)).

**My code:**

```
let transaction = contract.methods.myFunc();
let tx = {
    to: contract._address, 
    data: transaction.encodeABI(),
    gasPrice: GAS_PRICE,
    gas: await transaction.estimateGas()
};
let signedTransaction = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, PRIVATE_KEY);
await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction.rawTransaction);
```

However, executing the code above results with the following error:

```
Insufficient funds.
The account you tried to send transaction from does not have enough funds.
Required 63611 and got: 0.
```

Obviously, since the first approach completes successfully, there shouldn't be any issue of insufficient funds here.

Can anyone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: check for "from: ACCOUNT_ADDRESS"  in first case, whereas in second case no "from:" address is specified manually. is same from addresses are passed in both cases?

Comment: @kherwa: That is why I added a link to the documentation of each function. According to the documentation of `web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction`, the object passed to this function does not need to have a `from` field. By the way, I tried to add this field just in case they forgot to mention it in the docs, but got the same result.

Comment: I meant that, are both addresses same? One derived from PRIVATE KEY and ACCOUNT_ADDRESS used in first case.

Comment: @kherwa: In the first case, I use `ACCOUNT_ADDRESS` and `ACCOUNT_PASSWORD`.
In the second case, I use the `ciphertext` field given in the key file, where `ACCOUNT_ADDRESS` also appears.
So I'm assuming that the private key matches the account address.
BTW, I prefix this `ciphertext` with `0x`.

Comment: No private key is stored in encrypted form in key file.

Comment: You can use node.js module keyethereum for recovering plain private key from key file..

Comment: @kherwa: Awesome, thank you, I'm on it!!!, By the way, it's `keythereum`, not `keyethereum`.

Comment: @kherwa: Now that it's working, I have yet another problem. My initial procedure has allowed me to obtain the events fired during the execution of the function. With the new procedure, I am unable to do so. There is even an open issue on this in GitHub [here](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1377). Any ideas? Thank you. More precisely, the event is in the transactionHash, but not "as nicely" as it was before. For example, it is not under `events.MyEventName.returnValues`.

Comment: you could use returning promise as : web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction.rawTransaction).on('receipt', console.log);  this will return a promise which will be resolved when transaction receipt will become available. view here: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/callbacks-promises-events.html#promievent

Comment: This is the same receipt returned when the promise is resolved. Unlike with `contract.methods.myFunc().send()`, it does not explicitly contain the event fired by `myFunc`, and I need to "dig it" out of `logs.topics`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79044/discussion-between-kherwa-and-goodvibration).